# How to get the latitude and longitude points of a node in a graph in osmnx graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, polyline, osmnx

I constructed a graph and want to see the latitude and longitude values of each node in the graph. How can I find those?

I used `G.nodes` to find each node but I get some sort of ids.

```
import osmnx as ox

G = ox.graph_from_point((41.0911561, 29.0151246), distance=500)
print(G.nodes)
```

output : (shortened)

```
[2394717187, 2394717190, 3445170185, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a node with id = 2394717187, get it with this code:

```
node0 = G.nodes(data=True)[2394717187]
```

then, you can print its `long` and `lat` with:

```
print( node0['x'], node0['y'] )
```

The output will be:- 29.0119616 41.0892429

Comment: In this case `data=True` can be dropped without affecting the output.